# Worklight notification error in console.log

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying out module 41 of the getting started guide for notifications in worklight.

The isPushSupported returns true - isSubscribed returns false and the other 2 buttons are never enabled - which made me thing - problem!

So checking the console.log I see this :

```
 tail -f console.log 
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:480)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:207)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
  at [internal classes]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication():506'
com.worklight.server.auth.impl.WorkLightAuthenticationException
  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:506)
  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.login(AuthenticationContext.java:578)
  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.login(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:108)
  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.LoginOnDemandHandler.doPost(LoginOnDemandHandler.java:69)
  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:125)
  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.lockedGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:87)
  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:81)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
  at [internal classes]
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException():329'
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:329)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:305)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:198)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:174)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:518)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:480)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:207)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
  at [internal classes]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException():329'
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:329)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:305)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:198)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:174)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:518)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:480)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:207)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
  at [internal classes]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException():329'
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:329)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:305)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:198)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:174)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:518)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:480)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:207)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
  at [internal classes]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication():506'
com.worklight.server.auth.impl.WorkLightAuthenticationException
  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:506)
  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.login(AuthenticationContext.java:578)
  at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.login(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:108)
  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.LoginOnDemandHandler.doPost(LoginOnDemandHandler.java:69)
  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:125)
  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.lockedGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:87)
  at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:81)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
  at [internal classes]
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException():329'
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:329)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:305)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:198)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:174)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:518)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:480)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:207)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
  at [internal classes]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time. {SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.DEVICE), COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) FROM NOTIFICATION_DEVICE t0 INNER JOIN NOTIFICATION_USER t1 ON t0.USERSUBSCRIPTIONID = t1.ID WHERE (t0.APPLICATIONID IN (?, ?) AND t0.PLATFORM = ?)} [code=30000, state=42Z02]
```

The exception seems to fire each time i run the app. I see no exceptions client side.

Can somebody suggest the problem!? I have the apns-certificate-production.p12 in beside the application descriptor and my app seems fine otherwise.

Comment: Hi. You did not mention if you are trying this on a device or simulator, nor any steps you have taken that led you to getting the error. Also, is this done on a clean database and a fresh installation of the Worklight server?

Comment: IOS 6.0.1 iPad 4th gen. Yes done on clean database fresh server install.

Comment: Have you created a certificate for push notifications and placed it in your project's root as the training module indicates? Did you create an App ID (at Apples developer site) that has push enabled, signed your application with it, and have your device provisioned to use that app id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer was that these error messages were irrelevant to the actual problem - and the code was simply not being run due to a simple ')' being missed in one of the javascript files.